# Accelerometer cocos2d spritebuiilder cant get it to work

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer, spritebuilder

I am trying to use the accelerometer in my spritebuidler cocos2d project.I tried to follow https://www.makeschool.com/gamernews/371/accelerometer-with-cocos2d-30-and-ios-7 which seems pretty straight forward but it doesnt seem to work for me. I have tried downloading their git example but the project wont build.

my code is below

```
#import "GameOverScene.h"
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
@implementation GameOverScene{
    CCButton *_restartButton;
    CMMotionManager *_motionManager;
    CCLabelTTF *_label;
}
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _label= [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"X" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:48];
        [self addChild:_label];
        _motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)restartButtonClicked {
    CCScene *scene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene withTransition:[CCTransition transitionPushWithDirection:CCTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.25f]];
}
- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    _label.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2);
    [_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
}
- (void)onExit
{
    [super onExit];
    [_motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
}

- (void)update:(CCTime)delta {
    CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData = _motionManager.accelerometerData;
    CMAcceleration acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration;
    CGFloat newXPosition = _label.position.x + acceleration.y * 1000 * delta;
    newXPosition = clampf(newXPosition, 0, self.contentSize.width);
    _label.position = CGPointMake(newXPosition, _label.position.y);
}

@end
```

What happens is i see half an x on the bottom left corner when its meant to be in the middle of the screen.i tried changing the spawn position to

```
_label.position = ccp(500, 300);
```

and that changes the y axis but it is still on 0 on the x axis when i run the project
and tilting my phone does nothing.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Author of the tutorial here. Sorry for the hickup, I have updated the repository with the solution [on GitHub](https://github.com/MakeSchool/AccelerometerExampleCocos2d) and fixed the Cocos2D related issue, we will migrate this tutorial to Cocos2D 3.3 soon. If you download the latest version you should see everything working as expected.

Regarding your specific problem, could you inspect/print the `contentSize` of the scene to which you are adding the label?

Comment: Hi, no worries it actually worked the next day. I have no idea what it was or what fixed it